# How to push a variable in redis list - redis command line

Tags: redis

Please check the following commands,

```
redis /tmp/redis.sock> set s1 String1
OK
redis /tmp/redis.sock> set s2 String2
OK
redis /tmp/redis.sock> set s3 String3
OK
redis /tmp/redis.sock> LPUSH list s1 s2 s3
(integer) 3
redis /tmp/redis.sock> LRANGE list 0 -1
1) "s3"
2) "s2"
3) "s1"
redis /tmp/redis.sock>
```

When I have tried to push variable in redis list, the value was taken as a string. Is there any workaround for adding variables to list?

Thanks.

Comment: `s1`, `s2`, `s3` are actually keys added to Redis. Is that what you want?

Comment: @RaR I want to s1, s2 and s3 variable's value.

Comment: Redis-cli don't directly support variables. like javascript console in any browser. Your first step will set 3 redis keys(`s1`, `s2` and `s3`) and `s1`, `s2` and `s3` in push command will be treated as independent strings. You can't achieve what you are trying to do unless you use `Lua` script, I believe

Comment: Moreover, why can't you directly push it to the list, instead of assigning it to some variables and pushing it?

Comment: s1 in `set s1 String1` is not a variable. Just a string.

Answer (score 2):

The elements in a Redis List are Strings. You can not nest data structures or created references between them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use variables, you can use `Lua` script,

```
eval "redis.call('lpush', 'list', KEYS[1], KEYS[2], KEYS[3])" 3 String1 String2 String4
```

Refer [this](https://redis.io/commands/eval),

```
> eval "s1 = 'String1'" 0
> eval "s2 = 'String2'" 0
> eval "s3 = 'String3'" 0
> eval "redis.call('lpush', 'list', s1, s2, s3)" 0
```

Redis-cli may not allow to create global variables `s1`, `s2`, `s3`. To gain permission, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19998708/6048928